# WPF - Bind List<Person> Polymorphism

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I managed to create a grid and fill it with data of a generic `List`. For example `Person`. But in this List are `Man`, `Women` for example. How do I add a new row to the grid? I know, that I have to save it to the List but do not know how.

Sample XAML:

```
    <dxg:GridControl SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"  Name="Persons" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" AutoGenerateColumns="AddNew" EnableSmartColumnsGeneration="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding model.personList}">
        <dxg:GridControl.View>
            <dxg:TableView EditFormShowMode="Dialog" AllowPerPixelScrolling="True" NewItemRowPosition="Bottom" ShowTotalSummary="false" 
                           AllowEditing="True" InitNewRow="TableView_InitNewRow" ValidateRow="TableView_ValidateRow" InvalidRowException="TableView_InvalidRowException" />
        </dxg:GridControl.View>
    </dxg:GridControl>
```

Der Person class is abstract and has for example the property name. The class man and women have additional properties (just for example).

Comment: Can you show some sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set or bind the `ItemsSource` of the `DataGrid` to an `ObservableCollection`, you could just add instances of `Man` and `Woman` to this collection.

The difference between a `List<T>` and an `ObservableCollection<T>` is that the latter implements the [INotifyCollectionChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) interface which means that the `DataGrid` will be updated automatically as new items are added or removed.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var sourceCollection = Persons.ItemsSource as ObservableCollection<Person>;
    if (sourceCollection != null)
    {
        sourceCollection.Add(new Man() { Name = "..." });
    }
}
```

Comment: But if I want to add a new row with Type man I can not do that due the fact that it shows only the person columns right? I think, I will need an "editor" that inserts the row to the grid. The default "empty row" at the end won't work.

Comment: Sure you can provided that Man inherits from Person and you are binding to an IEnumerable<Person>.

Comment: But what if i need a women object to add it to the grid. I will try it with an editor. The "empty row" seems only to work, if I want to modify an existing object on the grid.

Comment: Of course both Man and Women must inherit from Person if you want to be able both kind of objects to an IList<Person>.

Comment: That I do understand but I do not understand how to provide this functionality on the grid. There are just columns of the person class. Both man and women extends person. I can add it to the list/collection but not to choose which type of object it is (on the grid).

Comment: Of course you must write some logic that decides whether you want to create a man or a woman. The grid won't do this for you.

Comment: Your Person class could have a Gender property, which could be set by a ComboBox in a DataGrid cell. No need for any derived Man or Woman classes.

Comment: If that is not possible which callback should I use from the grid? I will then map the column-values from the grid to the created object and add this object to the list. But I do not know which callback to use.

Comment: Do you see a blank row in the grid?

Comment: So Person is not an abstract class?

Comment: it is an abstract class.

Comment: So what kind of objects are created when you say that the grid "adds new records"?